# Changing the font of ax.text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am making a python plot using matplotlib.

At the start of the code, I use:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
```

in order to change the font of the text in my plots.

I also use:

```
ax.text(0.5,0.5, r'$test_{1}$', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', size=18)
```

But this text is not Times New Roman.

How do I make the `ax.text` Times New Roman?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Parameter `fontdict`

The [Axes.text matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) says:

> If fontdict is None, the defaults are determined by your rc parameters.

So you have to include `fontdict=None` in `ax.text()`, in order to display its font as specified in `rcParams`.

```python
ax.text(..., fontdict=None)
```

The `fontdict` parameter is available since [matplotlib 2.0.0](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html).

#### 2. Math expressions

Besides, for math expressions like `$a=b$`, [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#fonts) say:

> This default [font] can be changed using the **mathtext.default rcParam**. This is useful, for example, to use the same font as regular non-math text for math text, by **setting it to regular**.

So you also need to set the default font to 'regular':

```python
rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'
```

This option is available at least since [matplotlib 2.1.0](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#fonts)

#### 3. Example

Your code should now look something similar to:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
plt.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '$example$', horizontalalignment='center', 
        verticalalignment='center', size=18, fontdict=None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but it hasn't changed anything. The font is still sans serif. I am using matplotlib version 2.2.2

Comment: @user1551817 I've added a full example to my answer. I've run it with 2.2.2 and it works. Maybe the cause of the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like doing "$example$" instead of "example" is the difference.

Comment: @user1551817 you are right. I have completed my answer addressing math expressions