# Python Dython change x and y label font size

Tags: python, matplotlib

Could someone help me understand how to manipulate the below code in Python as part of the Dython package to change the x and y label font size on the heat map that this code produces?

```
import pandas as pd
from dython.nominal import associations

# Download and load data from UCI
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data')
df.columns = ['class', 'cap-shape', 'cap-surface', 'cap-color', 'bruises', 'odor', 'gill-attachment',
              'gill-spacing', 'gill-size', 'gill-color', 'stalk-shape', 'stalk-root', 'stalk-surface-above-ring',
              'stalk-surface-below-ring', 'stalk-color-above-ring', 'stalk-color-below-ring', 'veil-type',
              'veil-color', 'ring-number', 'ring-type', 'spore-print-color', 'population', 'habitat']

# Plot features associations
associations(df, theil_u=True, figsize=(15, 15))
```

Reading the documentation on the below link seems to suggest ax as a parameter on the associations method but I can't figure out how to tweak this

[Dython Association Method](http://shakedzy.xyz/dython/modules/nominal/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific configuration for the font size in this method, but as the heat-map is just another Matplotlib `ax`, you can change the font size using Matplotlib's methods. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102830/changing-the-font-of-ax-text-in-matplotlib). Note that `associations` returns the `ax` as part of its output dict, and you can set `plot=False` to prevent it from plotting.